# Calculate ratio between 2 moving averages fails

Tags: floating-point, pine-script

Trying to calculate how close moving average 20 and moving average 200 are using ratio.
It returns True for ALL values?
If I use only 1 condition same issue; all true

If I use 1 instead of fraction like 0.8 it works (xRatio<1)

Looks like float vs integer, rounding issue?

```
float ma1 = ta.sma(close, 20)
float ma2 = ta.sma(close, 200)
float xRatio = ma1/ma2
xNarrow = xRatio<1.2 and xRatio>0.8
plotchar(xNarrow, "xNarrow", "▲", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

My first pine steps.. appreciate help!

Comment: which language is this?

Comment: pine in TradeView

Comment: Is there any place in your data where the moving average using 20 samples is more than 1.2 or less than .8 times the moving average using 200 samples?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes. I have also used other wider and smaller ranges. When I use any 0.xx  value it simply does not seem to calculate correctly.